# I am using this cron "0 0 9 * * ?" expression for scheduling task at morning 9am every day,

Tags: java, spring, service, cron, scheduled-tasks

but problem is that task is triggering two times, one at morning 9am and second one at 2:30 afternoon, below is my code

@Service
public class NotificationScheduler {

```
@Autowired
private UsersService userService;

@Autowired
private SendSMS sendSms;

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 9 * * ?")
public void sendSmsNotifictaion() {
    DecimalFormat deciFormat = new DecimalFormat(); 
    deciFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(4);
    List<Users> userList=userService.getAllUserByIsNotSuAcc();
    userList.forEach(obj -> {
        String updatemsg="UPDATE:+Commission+Wallet+balance+for+"+obj.getName()+"+(AGENT+ID+"+obj.getId()+")+on+"+BaseDateUtil.getDateYYYYMMDD(new Date())+"+is+Rs.+"+deciFormat.format(BaseUtil.getDouble(obj.getBalance()))+".+Log+in+to+Spark+OMOB+to+view+and+transfer+balance.+Thank+you+for+your+trust+and+growth+with+us.+-+Spark+Team";
        sendSms.sendSMS(updatemsg, obj.getAgentmobil(), "");
    });
}
```

}

Comment: Have you read the documentation of that syntax?

Answer (score 2):

Your cron should be this `0 9 * * *` see [cronguru](https://crontab.guru/#0_9_*_*_*) for explanations